# Как извлечь число из строки. T-SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть строка -
"Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 5шт.) за подключение к системе «iBank 2» с применением  USB токена"
Нужно извлечь цифру - 5. Число штук. ,Чтобы потом использовать в запросе.

Как можно извлечь эту цифру?

Извлечь нужно в отдельный столбец.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947027/extract-regexp-substring-sql-server

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @t table (id int, coment_transaction varchar(100));
insert into @t (id, coment_transaction) values(1, 'Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 15шт.) за подключение к системе «iBank 2» с применением USB токена'), (2, 'какой-то товар в количестве 22 шт.');
    
    SELECT x.id, x.coment_transaction, LEFT(x.Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', x.Val+'!')-1) as [Total]
    from 
        (SELECT 
            t.id,
            t.coment_transaction,
            SUBSTRING(iif(PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) > 0, left(t.coment_transaction, PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) - 1), ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', iif(PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) > 0, left(t.coment_transaction, PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) - 1), '')), LEN(iif(PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) > 0, left(t.coment_transaction, PATINDEX('%шт.%', t.coment_transaction) - 1), ''))) Val
            from @t t
        ) x
```

Comment: Я наверное коряво вопрос задал... Есть столбец с такими комментариями. Из каждого комментария в новый столбец нужно извлекать цифру( число штук), чтобы потом новый столбец использовать в дальнейшем. Вот так.

Comment: Столбец называется , условно - coment_transaction

Comment: из вас прям вытягивать надо инфу =)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю ,что вместо этой строчки ('Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 15шт.) за подключение к системе «iBank 2» с применением USB токена') ,можно просто ссылку на столбец дать. Просто не все строки так называются, комиссии разные бывают)))

Comment: это просто значение в столбце вашей таблицы. для примера у меня таблица: declare @t table (id int, coment_transaction varchar(100));

Comment: поправил скрипт, добавил новое значение для столбца coment_transaction

Comment: Добавил картинку. Столбец ,в котором находятся значения. нужно извлечь именно " цифру" шт. В отдельный столбец. Ваш пример уникален для конкретного примера.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример не приводится. Поэтому стреляю с бедра.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и пример вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, comment_transaction NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (comment_transaction) VALUES
(N'Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 15шт.) за подключение к системе «iBank 2» с применением USB токена'), 
(N'Какой-то товар в количестве 22 шт.');
-- DDL и пример вставки данных, конец

DECLARE @exprToFind NCHAR(3) = N'шт.';

SELECT *
    , RIGHT(comment, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(comment)) - 1) AS Result
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(@exprToFind, comment_transaction)) AS t(pos)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRIM(LEFT(comment_transaction, pos - 1))) AS t1(comment);
```

**Результат**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
| id |                                       comment_transaction                                        | pos |             comment              | Result |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 15шт.) за подключение к системе «iBank 2» с применением USB токена |  33 | Комиссионное вознаграждение ( 15 |     15 |
|  2 | Какой-то товар в количестве 22 шт.                                                               |  32 | Какой-то товар в количестве 22   |     22 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Добавил картинку. Столбец ,в котором находятся значения. нужно извлечь именно " цифру" шт. В отдельный столбец. Ваши примеры уникальны для конкретного примера.

Comment: (1) Картинки не нужны. Пожалуйста, удалите.
Вам нужно добавить в вопросе раздел, как в моем ответе: `-- DDL и пример вставки данных, начало ... -- DDL и пример вставки данных, конец` (2) У вас была возможность попробовать мой ответ? Он должен работать с вашим набором данных.

Comment: Не понимаю .как её использовать в селекте у себя. К сожалению, нельзя картинку вставить в коммент.(

Comment: Вам нужно использовать только оператор SELECT... . И замените **@tbl** на ваше настоящее имя таблицы, а столбец **comment_transaction** — на ваше настоящее имя столбца.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myColumn VARCHAR(256) = 'Какие-то 5 пакетов в количестве (22 шт.)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@myColumn, PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', @myColumn) + 1, PATINDEX('% шт.)%', @myColumn) - (PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', @myColumn) + 1)) AS [Кол-во]
```

*псс: переменная @myColumn объявлена для отладки демонстрации, её можно удалить, а вместо неё подставить название вашего столбца*

Comment: Решение не будет работать для этого: `N'Какие-то 5 пакетов в количестве 22 шт.'`

Comment: Добавил картинку. Столбец ,в котором находятся значения. нужно извлечь именно " цифру" шт. В отдельный столбец. Ваши примеры уникальны для конкретного примера.

Comment: @AlexanderZhuzhgov поправил с учётом картинки, считаю что нужное число всегда в скобках перед подстрокой " шт."

Comment: Совершенно не понимаю, как в селекте ваш код с переменной использовать.                                                   DECLARE @myColumn VARCHAR(256) = cast(comment_transaction as varchar (255))
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@myColumn, PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', @myColumn) + 1, PATINDEX('% шт.)%', @myColumn) - (PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', @myColumn) + 1))  as [Кол-во] - У меня для всех значений в столбце должна вычленять число.

Comment: Переменная для примера, она вам не нужна. Вместо переменной нужно подставить название столбца. Меняем @myColumn на comment_transaction: SELECT SUBSTRING(comment_transaction, PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', comment_transaction) + 1, PATINDEX('% шт.)%', comment_transaction) - (PATINDEX('%(%шт.)%', comment_transaction) + 1)) AS [Кол-во]